# Is it possible to change the linting error color in VS Code in the tree?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has a feature where it will change the color of a filename in the file tree when there is a linting error. Unfortunately the error color looks a little harsh for me:
[image: VS Code File Tree]

Is there a way I can change the error color here? I know I can disable it completely with `problems.decorations.enabled`, but I would prefer to have them enabled, but just not be so hard on the eyes. I've gone through the theme customizations available [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference), but I haven't found anything related the the `problems.decorations`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two other settings you can look at:

```
  "explorer.decorations.colors": false,
  "explorer.decorations.badges": false
```

and some colorCustomizations (see [git decorator colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_git-colors))

> Git Colors
>
> `gitDecoration.modifiedResourceForeground`: Color for
>   modified git resources. Used file labels and the SCM viewlet.
>
> `gitDecoration.deletedResourceForeground`: Color for deleted git
>   resources. Used file labels and the SCM viewlet.
>
> `gitDecoration.untrackedResourceForeground`: Color for untracked git
>   resources. Used file labels and the SCM viewlet.
>
> `gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground`: Color for ignored git
>   resources. Used file labels and the SCM viewlet.
>
> `gitDecoration.conflictingResourceForeground`: Color for conflicting git
>   resources. Used file labels and the SCM viewlet.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to change the color of the problem colors.  Modified, untracked and ignored all work fine though.  You can change the file name color back to uncolored with the

```
  "explorer.decorations.colors": false,
```

setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
"list.errorForeground": "#00AA00"
```

This will change the color to green ("#00AA00").

In my case, I used it to add color to the High Contrast Theme because, for some reason, it was missing the error color in the file explorer.

Here's what I changed for that specific theme:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Default High Contrast]": {
        "list.errorForeground": "#00AA00"
    }
}
```